# Elemantary OS + Google Chrome: Chrome is opening new tabs with ad-content

Tags: google-chrome

I have elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki and Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit).
Every time i start my computer, i open Chrome with my tabs from last session. Every time i press anything (links, buttons etc.) for the first time that session, in any of the tabs, Chrome opens a new tab with ad-content. What's this? Virus?

And how do i run AV on elementary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest checking what extensions you have running in Chrome. It's likely not a virus or malware. Sounds like Chrome picked up a bad extension that is throwing ads at you.

But if you want to install and run antivirus [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/free-linux-antivirus-programs/) are some you can try.

Comment: I removed the extension "Fixer for Java", now i only have google docs, sheets and slides, and i have Lastpass (Password manager). Still it opens new tabs... :-/

Comment: ...and i don't have system rights to remove clamav to reinstall... ??

Comment: OK, check under Settings (in Chrome) in the On Starup section. Make sure what you want is selected there. My suspicion is that some malware you picked up along the way and it configured your browser to open ad pages. Maybe try setting it to "Open the New Tab Page".

Comment: Cleared my cache and changed to "Open new Tab Page#. Seems to work so far, but need to reboot to be sure.